# How to check the speed of ram when dmidecode command is not working

Tags: ram

Output of the dmidecode command is like this.

```
viki@viki-pc:~$ sudo dmidecode --type 17
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 17, 21 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0005
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: SODIMM1
    Bank Locator: Bank 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Unknown

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 17, 21 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0005
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: SODIMM2
    Bank Locator: Bank 1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: Unknown
```

[Update]

and lshw -c memory command is

```
viki@viki-pc:~$ sudo lshw -c memory
[sudo] password for viki: 
  *-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: R0190E7
       date: 05/07/2012
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 3008KiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int9keyboard int10video acpi usb agp smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 5
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 4GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3
          physical id: 0
          slot: SODIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: SODIMM2
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: a
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: internal write-through
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: b
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: internal write-through
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: c
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       capabilities: internal write-back
```

Basically it is supposed to give me the speed of the ram module but it is not giving the same.

Any other way to figure RAM's speed out?

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issues with dmidecode. I've found lshw to be helpful in instances like this.

Open a terminal (CTRL-ALT-T) should open a terminal in the current Xwindows session. Alternatively you can switch to a terminal with CTRL-ALT-F1 (in which case you will have to login.)

Regardless of how you get there, issue the command

`sudo lshw -c memory`

You should get output similar to this:

[image: ramspeed]

If this fails, you can usually find the speed of your RAM noted on the SODIMM itself (or a model number that you can reference to find the same) Also the specifications published for your system should provide this information.

Comment: Even this didn't work. I would really like to know what's wrong with my system. 

My output:

*-memory

       description: System Memory

       physical id: 5

       slot: System board or motherboard

       size: 4GiB

     *-bank:0

          description: SODIMM DDR3

          physical id: 0

          slot: SODIMM1

          size: 4GiB

          width: 64 bits

     *-bank:1

          description: SODIMM [empty]

          physical id: 1

          slot: SODIMM2

  *-cache:0

Comment: Please provide details.  What is the make and model of your system?

Comment: This appears to be a bug when dealing with SMBIOS 2.6 or greater patches that may resolve this appear to be available: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ocsinventory-unix-agent/+bug/882574

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in BIOS setup? If it is not visible even there, then I guess there is something odd going on with the system (maybe one of the hardware forums can provide better guidance).